# How do I alias gradle task as if it were called with -x parameter?

Tags: gradle

I want instead of `gradle cleanIdea idea -x compileJava -x compileTestJava`
call something like `gradle ideaNoRecompile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TaskExecutionGraph` to do it. First of all, you need to provide a custom task, named `ideaNoRecompile`, when during the configuration phase, you need to check, whether this graph contains `ideaNoRecompile` task (that means, that this task will be executed. And if this task should be executed, then you can use a closгre to skip all the tasks, you don't want to be executed. Something like this:

```
task ideaNoRecompile(dependsOn:idea) {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(ideaNoRecompile)) {
            compileJava.enabled = false
            compileTestJava.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another similar answer:

```
task ideaNoRecompile {
    finalizedBy allprojects*.tasks*.idea
    doFirst {
        def skipTasks = ['compileJava', 'compileMirah', 'processResources', 'classes', 'compileTestJava', 'compileTestMirah', 'processTestResources', 'testClasses', 'jar', 'mergeProperties', 'generateModuleManifest' ] as Set
        allprojects*.tasks*.each {
            if (skipTasks.contains(it.name))
                it.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```